# I am having problems when training a model on my gpu

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I want to train the BLIP model for image captioning. When I load the BLIP model to the GPU I keep getting this error:

`RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 20.00 MiB (GPU 0; 4.00 GiB total capacity; 3.29 GiB already allocated; 0 bytes free; 3.49 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF`

I have a 4GB GTX1050Ti.

```
from pynvml import *
nvmlInit()
h = nvmlDeviceGetHandleByIndex(0)
info = nvmlDeviceGetMemoryInfo(h)
print(f'total    : {info.total}')
print(f'free     : {info.free}')
print(f'used     : {info.used}')

total    : 4294967296
free     : 115585024
used     : 4179382272
```

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: It looks like the model you try to load is way larger than your VRAM. Check, e.g., this: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/finding-model-size/130275/2 to print out the required VRAM for a specific model.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60068277/free-up-the-memory-allocation-cuda-pytorch/72811699

I think there is similar answers, please check it.

Comment: @hpwww The model size is 943.8MB and the VRAM is 4018MB. It should work then right?